# GoogleMap suspending initializer with coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, maps, coroutine

I have created delegate to initialize `GoogleMap` instance which is using coroutine. Map fragment is dispalyed properly until I invoke any method on map reference, then map hangs and stop responding.
This is my delegate:

```
 class MapInitializer(private val setUp: GoogleMap.() -> Unit) : ReadOnlyProperty<AppCompatActivity, GoogleMap> {
    var instance: GoogleMap? = null

    override fun getValue(thisRef: AppCompatActivity, property: KProperty<*>): GoogleMap {
        return instance ?: thisRef.loadMap().apply(setUp).also { instance = it }
    }

    private fun AppCompatActivity.loadMap(): GoogleMap = runBlocking {
        async { registerCallback() }.await()
    }

    private suspend fun AppCompatActivity.registerCallback(): GoogleMap = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment).getMapAsync {
            continuation.resume(
                it
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that map thread is suspending but I have no idea why. Help please.

Comment: `runBlocking` blocks the thread.

Comment: @Zoe What else I can use instead as bridge between suspended and nonsuspend function?

Comment: @Zoe More important: why `runBlocking` block thread when I use `Map` reference?

Comment: `runBlocking` combined with `await` will prevent execution until the coroutine is complete. You call loadMap in getValue every single time, without caching the result. So you load it every time you retrieve it, blocking it every time you do so.

Comment: I have edited code in question to load map only on first invoke, but it didn't solve problem.

Comment: if the map itself lags, that's not something you can fix unless you get better hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183380/discussion-between-karol-kulbaka-and-zoe).

Comment: My main goal was to avoid `onMapReady` callback. Such approach is unreachable this way. Map must be loaded in UI thread. :/